# Autostarting Conky Weird Behaviour

Tags: shell-script, startup, conky

I've set conky to be started after logging in by creating the file `conky.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`, and adding the entry `conky.sh` to the Xfce startup applications list. `conky.sh` contains the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
conky

exit
```

Conky starts as expected, but I now have two conky-related processes permanently running: `conky` using 7MB of RAM and `conky.sh` using 1.4MB of RAM. Also the result of `whereis conky` is now:

```
conky: /usr/bin/conky /etc/conky /usr/lib/conky /usr/bin/X11/conky /usr/local/bin/conky.sh /usr/share/man/man1/conky.1.gz
```

Why has this happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like conky is running in the foreground. Try killing everything conky related and running it from a terminal, to see if it returns you to your prompt immediately or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two processes because one is the actual call to conky.sh and within conky.sh, you are calling the binary conky. You should be able to tell your startup application to call the conky binary 10 seconds after a system boot instead of telling it to call a script, which then calls the conky binary.

I use Gnome and Ubuntu shows it like this:

In Ubuntu/Unity:

Click the gear icon in the upper right hand corner of the top panel. SelectStartup Applications. Click Add. In the resulting dialog box give the name as "Conky" and the command as conky. Click add and close.

In Ubuntu/Gnome Shell

Press Alt+F2 to bring up the Run dialog. Type gnome-session-properties.Click the "Add" button. In the resulting dialog box give the name as "Conky" and the command as conky. Click add and close.

There is an area there for the seconds. Hope this helps you for XFCE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just give conky more time to start up.

I use 30 sec as default, see:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30 &&     # 30 for Gnome
conky -c ~/.conkymain
```

where .*conkymain* is the file that runs my conky configuration.

Cheers!